# Angularjs reuse calculated values

Tags: angularjs

I need to use a calculated value to hide elements and do other things in the template.

```
<button ng-hide="expensive()" ng-click="foo()">foo</button>
<button ng-show="expensive() && otherFunction()" ng-click="bar()">bar</button>
<span ng-show="expensive()">Bas</span>
```

This causes the excecution of `expensive()` multiple times for each `$digest` cycle.
I want to reuse its result, but it needs to be executed for each digest - just not multiple times per digest.

Is there any best practice for reuse function results that needs to be re-calculated each digest?

*** update ***
This function works with a huge object and its properties can be changed with a lot of input fields and sub-formulars on the page. It has multiple one to many relations. If I have to add events / ngChanges to each field and if I miss only one, this will not work correcly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really give us enough information to give you the best option for your situation.

**Very generally speaking, the best option is to have whatever interactions that cause the return value of `expensive()` to change update a $scope.property and just use that in your view.**

In other words, don't use functions on scope in your view unless you're setting up a binding like ng-click or something. Instead, update properties on your scope whenever they need updating and just reference them directly.

Caution: This might tempt you to use $watch... don't do that. There are cheaper, more effective ways to trigger updates, like ngChange, or other such events.

Comment: You are right with scope properties. The problem is, this function works with huge objects and their properties can be changed with a lot of input fields and sub-formulars. It has multiple one to many relations. If I have to add events / ngChanges to each field and if I miss only one, this will not work correcly.

Comment: What's changing them? Handle those events.

Comment: A human is changing them. Preparing all those input fields could leet to errors if one is not prepared. eventhandler like ngChange are not the way to go in this case IMHO

Comment: Well, that's why we have end to end tests. ;)  But whatever works for you. It's just more efficient and effective to handle the events.

Comment: You are right. I hoped I would not need to test each single input field, but it's more secure this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. make expensive() a $q promise. Angular templates understand $q promises and resolve them accordingly
2. store the value when running the function, if the value exists return it first thing in the function. You can add a flush param to it in case you want to flush the cached value.
3. If the values truly never change once computed, you could put them in a resolve
4. If these values are the result of some DOM work, create a directive to do this and $emit actual changes to the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<button ng-hide="result" ng-click="foo()">foo</button>
<button ng-show="result && otherFunction()" ng-click="bar()">bar</button>
<span ng-show="expensive()">Bas</span>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.expensive = function() {
    ... do stuff ...
    $scope.result = ...;
    return $scope.result;
}
```

Comment: This is not my case, but if expensive() returns an object which is equal for each call where the used variables are equal, but the object is not the same instance, this runs in a loop and causes "ncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"